# Can I write a query into the command line of MySQL that tells me the amount of bytes in all tables of a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to get the amount of bytes in all tables of a database but can only figure out how to find out the amount of MB. Is there a way to get a more specific measurement of data?

Thanks
Nicolle

Comment: multiply the MB value with 1000000?  1 MB = 1000000 bytes

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? What is wrong with that given amount?

Answer (score 0):

To check table sizes f XXXX database and yyyy table

```
SELECT 
table_name AS `Table`, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "XXXX"  AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";
```